# ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED ---- Issues in Next js JWT implementation. How to solve this?

Tags: deployment, jwt, next.js13

I'm trying to implement JWT with package named 'jose' but it shows this issue-  {
code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './server.edge' is not defined by "exports" ----How can I solve this problem??

I've  update and reinstall npm, next js and jose but it didn't work.